# How to reorder a ListBox's bound ItemsSource without access to the underlying collection?

Tags: wpf

I have created a control derived from a WPF ListBox that allows me to reorder the contents of the ListBox by dragging and dropping. I do this with the below code:

```
ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
ListBox.Items.Insert(targetIndex, droppedObject);
```

The problem shows up when I bind an ObservableCollection to this derived class's ItemsSource. When bound, an exception is thrown when I try to access the ListBox.Items and edit it. It instead wants me to edit the ObservableCollection instead. This makes sense to me, but I don't have access to this collection in the .cs file of my derived ListBox class. Since the implementation of my derived control should be generic, I shouldn't ever access a global ObservableCollection within it. I have attempted to access the ListBox's ItemsSource and try and do my updates to it, but I cannot seem to cast it into a list that allows me to easily edit it without knowing what the contents are. Is there an easy fix to this issue that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I cannot seem to cast it into a list that allows me to easily edit it without knowing what the contents are

You need to make sure that the type assigned to the `ItemsSource` property actually supports re-ordering of items, i.e. that it implements the `IList` interface. Otherwise you cannot use the `RemoveAt` and `Insert` methods.

Cast using the `as` operator:

```
var sourceCollection = ListBox.ItemsSource as IList;
if(sourceCollection != null)
{
    sourceCollection.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
    sourceCollection.Insert(targetIndex, droppedObject);
}
```

If you get a `null` reference back, it means that the source collection doesn't implement the `IList` interface and you cannot move an item based on an index.

Comment: Thanks for your clean answer. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the correct way to do it is to actually reorder items in the underlying ItemsSource. I mean, you *can* coerce ListView to apply its own ordering (e.g. binding ItemsSource to a custom CollectionView instead), but things will get very messy when underlying collection changes. Personally, I'd avoid that route.

The proper answer would depend on why exactly do you want to order items and whether the ViewModel and Model layers should react to this reordering somehow (e.g. save the new items layout somewhere so it won't disappear after application is restarted). Normally, ViewModels are not expected to listen on changes to their ObservableCollections, but would rather accept 'MoveUp'/'MoveDown' commands from view and alter ObservableCollection accordingly.

On the other hand, if you're not creating an externally reusable library, and can guarantee that your ViewModels will not freak out if View starts to actually moving items around bound collection, its a relatively safe bet to just cast ItemsSource to non-generic `IList` interface and manipulate the items directly, as you suggested. Note that theoretically a bound collection may not implement `IList`, but in a real world application it almost certainly would.

Comment: I'm not using any real MVVM pattern. I just created a ListBox with drag and drop reordering capabilities. I wanted it to be reusable throughout the application for multiple lists of all kinds of different classes. This was why it was important that the ListBox control not have any idea what type of list it was referencing. I guess I cannot create a control used only for displaying, and also allow it to touch the list without knowing enough about it.

Comment: So, did you try casting ItemsSource to IList and swapping items inside it? It should work for your scenario.

Comment: @RichardJones I believe you should use MVVM as @Chriso said. There are libraries that separate view part of drag'n'drop from the view-model one. I use [WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop). With it you implement reordering logic in view-model that implements some interface – `IDropTarget`. Every draggable element implements `IDragSource`. So view doesn't know anything about unerlying data except it implement specific interface.

Comment: @Maxim MVVM is a large, complex solution to a small problem. Along with the fact that I don't know the pattern well enough to implement it without taking the extra time to learn it, a simple code update, like the one suggested, solved my problem.

Comment: @Chriso Casting to an IList worked. I accepted the other answer because it is cleaner. Thanks for your response.